# C# console calls Batch Multiple Batch files

Tags: c#, batch-file

there, 
I have two batch files: `BatchA.bat`, `BatchB.bat`
`BatchA.bat` is calling `B1.bat`, `B2.bat`, `B3.bat` and runs the three batch files at the same time (the three batch files' running order does not matter).
this is `BatchA.bat`:

```
start B1.bat
start B2.bat
start B3.bat
```

`BatchB.bat` is calling `B4.bat`, `B5.bat`, `B6.bat` and runs the three batch files at the same time (the three batch files' running order does not matter).
this is `BatchB.bat`:

```
start B4.bat
start B5.bat
start B6.bat
```

I am using C# console application to call `BatchA.bat`, `BatchB.bat`, but I need to make sure `BatchB.bat` won't start until `BatchA.bat` if finished. In other words, I need to make sure all `B1.bat`, `B2.bat` and `B3.bat` complete before I start `BatchB.bat`

This is the C# code:

```
proc.StartInfo.FileName = BatchA.bat;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
int exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
proc.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Process Complete! exitCode: " + exitCode.ToString());

proc.StartInfo.FileName = BatchB.bat;
proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
proc.Start();
proc.WaitForExit();
exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
proc.Close();
Console.WriteLine("Process Complete! exitCode: " + exitCode.ToString());
```

When I run this, all 6 batch files start at the same time. How do I make sure `BatchA.bat` is not complete until all three small batch files are complete?

Comment: Call BatchB from BatchA.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way of doing it could be to pipe the `start` commands. When the child processes end, the left part of the pipe will be closed, closing the full pipe and batch execution will continue

So, `batchA.cmd` could be coded as

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    echo starting BatchA
    (
        start "b1" cmd /c b1.cmd
        start "b2" cmd /c b2.cmd
        start "b3" cmd /c b3.cmd
    ) | more

    echo BatchA has ended
```

**note**: this method, while simple, can have a drawback (or not, it depends on the needs). Processes started by the `b1`...`b3` can keep the pipe active.

@Squashman has already posted the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39981233/2861476) to handle not waiting for the processes started from inner batch files.

Comment: That's a clever way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This will launch all three batch files in their own window in parallel and waits for all three to finish before it launches batchb.

```
 @echo off
 start "" /wait cmd /c batch1.bat |start "" /wait cmd /c batch2.bat |start "" /wait cmd /c batch3.bat
 batchb.bat
```

Comment: This will not ensure `B1` or `B2` have ended.

Comment: @MCND, updated my code.  Not as clean as yours though.

Comment: Actually you have posted the code I was going to include to handle behaviour pointed in my answer. Coding the pipes this way will not wait for the processes started from `b1`...`b3`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `WAITFOR`. In Batch A, use this:

```
@echo off
waitfor done
waitfor done
waitfor done
echo done
```

Then in B1, B2, B3, use `WAITFOR /SI done` when the batch is done running.

Alternatively, you could create a 0-byte marker file in each of B1, B2, and B3 as a monitor, checking for the existence of any before ending Batch A, but is probably more complicated.

Comment: I had to use this to get it to work. `WAITFOR /S %computername% /SI done`

Comment: Huh, I wonder what the difference is. I did not require it when running on the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way to do this with batch files.  The "start" command launches a process, and gives you *no* handle by which to check if the process is done, or wait until it's done.

It is possible to do this via powershell commands.

```
PS > $x = Start-Process notepad -PassThru
PS > Wait-Process -Id $x.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying using await and async. By using the await keyword you could continue other work until BatchA is complete.

For example,

```
  Task<int> getBatchAData = GetBatchDataAsync();

    if (batchAData != 0)
    {
       GetBatchB();
    }

   var yourData = await getBatchAData;
```

Additonal information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx